# What is the single most influential book about website promotion and internet marketing?

Tags: books, marketing

What is the single most influential, useful, famous book about website promotion and internet marketing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the best, it is a subjective opinion.

But one, that is definitely in top 20 and I personally thought was worth a read was Seth Godin book : "Purple Cow".